# How do I change the color of the navbar in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap 3 does not have the customize option yet.

The color of the navbar for the carousel template is blackish. I would like to change that to `#4169E1`. I already have a `custom.css` file that is linked beneath the `bootstrap.css` reference. What would I put into my `custom.css` to change the color of the navbar?

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bootstrap/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: maybe background-color: #yourcolor. you should show some code here though, or make a jsfiddle so we can help better

Comment: There you go Bobo. That is what I put in the index.html doc for the carousel template

Answer (score 5):

custom.css:

```
.navbar-inverse {
   background-color: #4169E1;
}
```